# How to use the contents of a list to output a new list?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am looking to find a way on how to use the contents of a list of one type, to output a list of another for use in a game.

```
data Dir   = N | E | S | W deriving (Show,Eq)
data Steps = Forward | Right | Back | Left deriving Show

quickGame :: Dir -> [Dir] -> [Steps]
quickGame d [] = []
```

So if `quickGame N [S,W,E,N,N]` was the input, I would receive in return [Back,Right,Back,Left,Forward].

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried an if then else to go through the list to output the second, but there must be a cleaner way?

Comment: Why isn't this `[Back, Right, Left, Forward, Forward]`?

Comment: Using pattern matching on data constructors seems the cleanest way to me but I don't get how your sample input/output works. Are you sure it is correct as is?

Comment: Can you explain, in words, how you obtain the output list from the input list in your example? You've got two `N` going to different outputs, so it clearly depends on more than just a one-to-one mapping. What is your proposed algorithm?

Comment: You probably want to make a stronger distinction between the direction you are *facing* and the direction in which you *move*. For instance, if you are facing north and take a step south, the results in you facing south. Facing south and taking a step to the west results in you facing west (as opposed to going *east* if you were still facing east).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're going to run into a conflict with the built-in `Left` and `Right` constructors for the `Either` type, so let's redefine:

```
data Step = F | R | B | L deriving Show
```

Then, let's define a helper that compares our current direction with the new direction, and returns an appropriate step.  It's tedious, but relatively straightforward.

```
step :: Dir -> Dir -> Step
step N N = F
step N E = R
step N S = B
step N W = L
step E N = L
step E E = F
step E S = R
step E W = B
step S N = B
step S E = L
step S S = F
step S W = R
step W N = R
step W E = B
step W S = L
step W W = F
```

Now, `quickGame` can be expressed recursively by comparing the current direction (first argument) to the next direction (first element of the second argument) and outputting the appropriate step, and then recursively calling `quickGame` with the new direction as "current":

```
quickGame :: Dir -> [Dir] -> [Steps]
quickGame cur (nxt:rest) = step cur nxt : quickGame nxt rest
quickGame _ [] = []
```

The final code:

```
data Dir  = N | E | S | W deriving Show
data Step = F | R | B | L deriving Show

quickGame :: Dir -> [Dir] -> [Step]
quickGame cur (nxt:rest) = step cur nxt : quickGame nxt rest
quickGame _ [] = []

step :: Dir -> Dir -> Step
step N N = F
step N E = R
step N S = B
step N W = L
step E N = L
step E E = F
step E S = R
step E W = B
step S N = B
step S E = L
step S S = F
step S W = R
step W N = R
step W E = B
step W S = L
step W W = F

main = do
  print $ quickGame N [S,W,E,N,N]
```